# What happens if a block signer goes offline on Rinkeby?

Tags: rinkeby, proof-of-authority

Rinkeby relies on a sequence of trusted signers to add blocks to its test chain. What happens if one of these block signers goes offline? How long is the next node in the list supposed to wait before submitting its own block, and how do other nodes know that they weren't Sybil'd out from the supposedly offline node?

Answer (score 2):

I know how it works in POA.network and Kovan chains. They are using Authority Round consensus which is based on round robin mechanism.
So, if a validators gets offline, it will miss his turn and create a network delay for the time of the block.

Example:

`blocktime = 5 seconds.

block 13 created at: 11:10:15
block 14 created at: 11:10:20`

next block should be created by a validator which is offline, therefore

`block 15 created at: 11:10:30`

as you can see because of the validator was offline, the network delayed for 5 seconds.

Not sure how it works in rinkeby, but if it's round robin, it should be the same

Answer (score 2):

In Rinkeby (geth Clique PoA) for a network with N authorities (a.k.a. signers/sealers), each authority is only allowed to propose a block every `N/2 + 1` blocks. Thus, at any point in time there are at most `N − (N/2 + 1)` authorities allowed to propose a block. Authorities that are in-order are receiving a time advantage, because other potential authorities will delay the submission of their block by `rand(N * 500ms)`.

So for N > 2, if an authority goes offline fo some reason, there are `N − (N/2 + 1) - 1` other potential authorities that can jump in with a short delay of `rand(N * 500ms)`.

For details see "https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/225" and "[PBFT vs Proof-of-Authority:
Applying the CAP Theorem to Permissioned Blockchain](http://ceur-ws.org/Vol-2058/paper-06.pdf)"